# SQL: Remove records from table A that don't exist in table B based on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

this is probably something simple but I can't wrap my head around it.  I've tried IN, NOT EXISTS, EXCEPT, etc... and still can't seem to get this right.

I have two tables.

```
Table A
-----------

BK
NUM

Table B
------------

BK
NUM
```

How do I write a query to remove all records from table A, that are not in table B based on the two fields.   So if  Table A has a record where BK = 1 and NUM = 2,  then it should look in table B.  If table B also has a record where BK = 1 and NUM = 2 then do nothing, but if not, delete that record from table A.    Does that make sense?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so

```
delete from tablea
where (BK,NUM) not in 
(select BK,NUM from tableb)
```

using `exists`

```
delete from tablea a
where not exists
(select 1 from tableb where BK=a.BK and NUM = a.NUM)
```

Comment: ...which should be completely db-agnostic, too

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use an anti-join pattern, a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and then a predicate in the WHERE clause that filters out all matches.

It's easiest to write this as a SELECT first, test it, and then convert to a DELETE.

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM tablea t
  LEFT
  JOIN tableb s
    ON s.BK  = t.BK
   AND s.NUM = t.NUM
 WHERE s.BK IS NULL
```

The LEFT JOIN returns all rows from **`t`** along with matching rows from **`s`**.  The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause... we know that **`s.BK`** will be non-NULL on all matching rows (because the value had to satisfy an equality comparison, in a predicate in the ON clause). So **`s.BK`** will be NULL only for rows in **`t`** that didn't have a matching row in **`s`**.

For MySQL, changing that into a DELETE statement is easy, just replace the `SELECT` keyword with `DELETE`.  (We could write either `DELETE t` or `DELETE t.*`, either of those will work.

(This is an illustration of only one (of several) possible approaches.)